# Is there any method known in the Mathematical Statistics that proves that the prime numbers are not randomly distributed?

Tags: statistics, soft-question, prime-numbers, math-history

I am asking for my curiosity. Maybe everyone knows the answer to that question. I do not know. I don't have a maths education.

> Is there any method known in the Mathematical Statistics that proves that the prime numbers are not randomly distributed?

I mean, without knowing what "mechanism" is, is there a method to show this? Is there such a method in statistics? What I'm talking about, for example, can be a method based on "observation".

Otherwise, does the distribution of prime numbers have nothing to do with Statistics?

Comment: Primes are deterministic. There are no coin flips involved in whether $315418794126913$ is a prime or not, so they are not randomly distributed. However, it is still a sensible question to ask about their statistical properties.

Comment: Primes are deterministic, but random models do predict certain behaviors relatively well. Look here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/254a-supplement-4-probabilistic-models-and-heuristics-for-the-primes-optional/ The strongest model of which is the GUE hypothesis. (I do not claim to understand anything more than the most basic stuff here.)

Comment: The primes are not randomly distributed but there is a very large of functions such that $\sum_{p \le x} f(p) =\sum_{n \le x} \frac{f(n)}{\ln n}+O(\sum_{n \le x} \frac{|f(n)|}{\ln^2 n})$. That very large class excludes the functions defined in terms of the primes. So in some sense, the "randomness" conjecture is that if you don't define a function in term of the primes, then it really doesn't depend on the primes.. As if the function $isprime$ was a random variable independent to all the random variables not explicitly depending on it.

Comment: Google "distribution of primes" and you'll probably find something that suits your tastes. Like this, for example: http://math.uni.lu/eml/projects/reports/prime-distribution.pdf

Comment: @reuns Is this function you are writing based on observation?

Comment: @Beginner Please specify what you mean with "random". The answer heavily depends on the definition of "random". Of course, it is no coincidence that some number is prime or not. But noone found a (useful) pattern yet (which does not mean that there is none). If you accept : "all primes greater than $3$ are of the form$6k\pm1$" as a pattern, the answer is "yes". If you search for a clear structure which numbers are prime and which are not covering the complete set of the primes, the answer is almost surely "no".